# Google Native Client: Internet Explorer error

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer, google-nativeclient

I'm developing a PNaCl project and a requirement is to run this on Internet Explorer 11.
I have started with the [Google Native Client tutorial,](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/tutorial/tutorial-part1) with the "Part1" example., and now I'm stuck.
All indicate that the native Client Module has loaded successfully, but when I try to send a message to the PNaCl module, written in C++, I got the next error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'postMessage'

the line where I got the error is:

> HelloTutorialModule.postMessage("Hello");

I'm thankful for your help. :)

Comment: I notice it uses `PostMessage` rather than `postMessage` elsewhere in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNaCl currently isn't supported by Internet Explorer. You may want to try using [Pepper.js](http://trypepperjs.appspot.com/) or [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) when targeting non-Chome browsers.